# How to get date from day name?

Tags: sql-server

How can I get the date of specific day ? Like if I have Thursday or month number ?

If I give 12 for instance I want to get the date of 12th day of this month. Or if I give 'Sun' or 'Sat' is it possible to get the dates of these days ?

Comment: what is your table name and what column needed to this ?

Comment: @HamzaNig I don't have any table. Let's say I declare a number. I need to extract date of that day number of month. or if I declare a day name I want to get the date for that day of week

Comment: I dont understand, if you have month_number, and you type a number (20) then your date is 20.month_number,
what you want to get?

Comment: So, you've been given `Sun` and I assume today isn't Sunday. Are we asking for the nearest Sunday in the future? The nearest one in the past? And are there week ending rules that change this (IOW, are we asking for "Sunday of this week" and if so how is a week defined)?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever your are right Sun means Sunday noted but which Sunday? First week, last week or any other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function can construct a date from day, month and year.

[DATEPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) does the opposite - gives you the day, month, year, hour, etc. of a date. Or you can use functions like [YEAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [MONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [DAY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You can deconstruct the value returned by [GETDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function and construct whatever date you want. Here is for example how to get the date for 12th day of the current month:

```
select DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 12)
```

Converting 'Sun' or 'Sat' to date is a bit more difficult. First, they aren't quite deterministic. If today is Friday, "Sunday this week" means "next Sunday" in some parts of the world and "last Sunday" in others. You should implement your own logic based on the value returned by `DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())` (which will give you the day of the week).

Answer (score 1):

To find the weekday of the current month

```
DECLARE @daynumber INT = 12

SELECT datename(weekday, dateadd(d, @daynumber - 1, getdate()))
```

To find the dates of the current month of a given weekday

```
DECLARE @dayname char(3) = 'sat'

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECt TOP 
    (datediff(D, eomonth(getdate(), -1),eomonth(getdate())))
    dateadd(d,row_number()over(ORDER BY 1/0),
      eomonth(getdate(),-1))date
  FROM
    (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))x(x),
    (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))y(x)
)
SELECT day(date) monthday, date
FROM CTE
WHERE left(datename(weekday, date),3) = @dayname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sysdatetime(); --2018-12-13 16:29:56.0560574

---If I give 12 for instance I want to get the date of 12th day of this month.
declare @numDate int = 12;
select dateadd(m, datediff(m,0,getdate()),@numDate - 1 ); --2018-12-12 00:00:00.000

--Or if I give 'Sun' or 'Sat' is it possible to get the dates of these days ?
declare @text nvarchar(20) = 'Sunday';
declare @dateStart date =  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, sysdatetime()), 0),
    @days int =( select (DAY(dateadd(dd,-1,DATEADD(m,1,cast(2018 as varchar(4)) + '-' + cast(12 as varchar(2)) +'-01')))));
declare @dateEnd date = DATEADD(day,@days-1,@dateStart);
;WITH CTE (Dates,EndDate) AS
(
    SELECT @dateStart AS Dates,@dateEnd AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,Dates),EndDate
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE DATEADD(day,1,Dates) <= EndDate
)
SELECT CTE.Dates, DATENAME(DW, CTE.Dates)
FROM CTE
where DATENAME(DW, CTE.Dates)  = @text;
```

### Result:

```
Dates,Day
2018/12/2,Sunday
2018/12/9,Sunday
2018/12/16,Sunday
2018/12/23,Sunday
2018/12/30,Sunday
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Here is how to get week day name to week day number
DECLARE @T TABLE (Dow INT, NameOfDay VARCHAR(15), ShortName CHAR(3));

WITH Days AS
(
    SELECT TOP 7
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY object_id ORDER BY object_id) AS RowNo
    FROM
        sys.all_columns
)
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT
    RowNo,
    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, RowNo - 1),
    LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, RowNo - 1), 3)
FROM
    Days

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @T;

-- Here is how to get start of period
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfDay,
    DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfWeek,
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfMonth,
    DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfYear;

-- An example
WITH
StartPeriods AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS StartOfWeek
),
SelectedDay AS
(
    SELECT
        Dow - 1 AS Dow,
        (SELECT StartOfWeek FROM StartPeriods) AS StartOfWeek
    FROM
        @T
    WHERE
        ShortName = 'Wed'
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, Dow, StartOfWeek)
FROM
    SelectedDay;
```